Easter Hunt Challenge - Stuck
I am currently stuck at the following challenge. Someone know the answer?
The headmaster of a boarding school has installed a sundial with compass winds. To explain the 360° of a compass to his pupils he thinks up an Easter hunt starting from the sundial. As the pupils need some exercise each egg should be at least 160m from all others.
Let's go easter hunt
The headmaster of a boarding school has installed a sundial with compass winds. To explain the 360° of a compass to his pupils he thinks up an Easter hunt starting from the sundial.
As the pupils need some exercise each egg should be at least 160m from all others.
He:
Hides an egg always on the full degree (e.g. 0° or 37°)
Hides exactly one egg on each degree, in total 360 eggs.
Observes the distance rule with at least 160m (>= 160m)
Moves away from the sundial only when necessary and always as less as possible
Moves always clockwise
Hides the next egg as close as possible to the last
Hides the first egg directly north on 0° 160m from the sundial
Your task is to determine the degree and the distance of each egg.
Task 1:
When given the number 1 for the first egg – the degree shall be 0 and distance 160.
SOLVED.
Task 2:
And for any other given number between 1 and 360 for the hidden egg - you can return the correct degree and distance.
UNSOLVED
Question: How to solve the mathematical problem here? Any idea?
I tried it with and without the import module.
My code:
import math


class EasterHuntPython:
     @staticmethod



def calculate_nth_egg(egg_number: int) -> (int, float):
    
    if not (1 <= egg_number <= 360):
        raise ValueError("Peep")

    golden_angle = 137.50776405003785
    MIN_DISTANCE = 160.0
    

    if egg_number == 1:
        return 0, MIN_DISTANCE

    previous_eggs = [(0, MIN_DISTANCE)]

    for i in range(2, egg_number + 1):
        
        angle = (previous_eggs[-1][0] + golden_angle) % 360
        distance = previous_eggs[-1][1] + MIN_DISTANCE


        while True:
            valid = True
            for prev_angle, prev_distance in previous_eggs:
                angle_diff = abs(angle - prev_angle)
                angle_diff = min(angle_diff, 360 - angle_diff)
                radian_diff = math.radians(angle_diff)

                distance_between_eggs = math.sqrt(
                    distance ** 2 + prev_distance ** 2 -
                    2 * distance * prev_distance * math.cos(radian_diff)
                )

                if distance_between_eggs < MIN_DISTANCE:
                    distance += 1
                    valid = False
                    break
            if valid:
                break

        previous_eggs.append((angle, distance))

    return round(angle), round(distance, 4)

